# Angular Mat-Table how to span the header row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use multiple header rows in Mat Table. I can span the columns but failed on spanning on the row.

Please see my [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-awkj65?file=app/table-basic-example.html)

I want the last column "Cost" across the rows. But I can't get rid of the extra 'cost" column like in the image.

[image: cost column]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
  <!-- Position Column -->
 

     <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Cost Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cost </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cost}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Header row first group -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-first-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.text-align]="center" [attr.colspan]="2">
          First group
        </th>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Header row second group -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-second-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2"> Second group </th>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="header-col-third-group">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="1" [attr> cost </th>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Header row third group -->
    
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['header-row-first-group', 'header-row-second-group']"></tr>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: It's not right since it displays two "Cost" words. Can you try it?

Comment: I updated it and now its a single column, however you're table still needs some work because of the third column - it needs to be expanded to the first and second row. will continue with it for a minute.

Comment: Don't think so. I can achieve the same result without using the third-group. And please post you stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to decide which one you want to delete the word cost from. you are the one that inserted it twice.  to fix this immediately and get rid of it on the top line type or vice versa to the bottom.  Or you have to completely remove this line and only leave the latter.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-third-group">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="1"></th>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I want the word "Cost" cross the rows but your code doesn't work.